# How can one find a job after working as a freelancer?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, programming-languages

I was looking for a StackExchange site that would be the best for this question, so if this isn't the best place, please feel free to redirect me elsewhere.

I have worked as a Freelancer somewhat out of concern that I would flop on the quote coding interview unquote.  I ran across a book called the self-taught programmer who learned skills over a year's time and then got a job.  I have heard something similar one a training website.  It seems that such persons would not have the same exposure to the skills taught in a full 4+ year Computer Science or Software Engineering degree program.

How would you, if you were in my position, find a job and feel confident going into an interview.  How could people like those mentioned above, feel confident when going into an interview or how would they know what to expect in an interview?  To answer this, I should add a few details.  My studies and work as a freelance Web Developer/SW Engineer/Programmer have been spread over the past several years.  When I got my degree in Computer Engineering in 1989, I didn't have a course on Algorithms.  I worked in a different field and then returned to this technology field several years ago.

In order to feel confident with Algorithms, I felt that I needed to review Calculus, Probability and Statistics.  I also learned Discrete Math.  Because of an interest in Machine Learning, I also studied Linear Algebra, and etc.  Now, I can better approach the study of algorithms.  The point is that it would be hard to imagine learning various languages, developing applications, learning all this math and then learning Algorithms.  Certainly all that could not be done in just one year.  In addition, these stories I heard on some training websites mention various success stories, and yet none of those sites have any courses on Algorithms, Design Patterns or even Math.

Since, I am only now able to jump into studying algorithms, initially, I need a job that does not require a "coding interview."  How can I find the jobs that will not make me look unskilled?  Maybe I need to find recruiters and say this is where I am and this is my limitation.

Thanks in advance for any direction,
Bruce

Comment: This site is for technical questions about computer science.  I'm afraid that requests for career advice, interviewing advice, or discussion about job searches are off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].